# Positioning a heading relative to (above) an absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have a block `<div>` I want to define with precise pixel coordinates via `position: absolute`, but I want to position a heading above its parent `<div>`. If the font-size changes (or the user enlarges the text), the block `<div>` must stay in exactly the same place, but the heading may move up/down to accommodate the larger/smaller text.

Here is some sample code that, honestly, doesn't come close, but may help to  illustrate the problem. It's just one of the variations I tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Positioning Test</title>
<style>
    #box1 { border: red 1px solid; }
    #box1 h4 { margin: 0; color: blue }
    .inner_box {
        background: #aaf;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .target_pos {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    #marker {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box1">
    <h4>Heading</h4>
    <div class="inner_box target_pos">
        This is the <strong>inner_box</strong>.
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Marks where the inner_box should begin -->
<div id="marker" class="target_pos"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The idea is the blue `inner_box` must be positioned exactly at the `marker` (which it is), but the `Heading` text must be directly above it, and the red 1px border should enclose everything.

Here is how it looks in Firefox:

[image: Actual code from Firefox]

And here's how I would like it to look instead:

[image: Mockup of desired appearance]

Since I have several of these boxes to work with, and their positions may change depending on viewport size, and the heading font/text will vary, I need a dynamic solution, here. I would prefer pure CSS3, but if JS is required, I could live with  that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you that works for any font size, position and number of boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/y73sqdr9/3/

Also

HTML

```
<div class="box target">
    <h1>Headingggggggggg</h1>
    <div class="inner">
        This is the <strong>inner_box</strong>.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="square target"></div>

<div class="box target2">
    <h1>Headingggggggggg</h1>
    <div class="inner">
        This is the <strong>inner_box</strong>.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="square target2"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-top: none; }

.box h1 {
    margin: -2em -1px -1px;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: none;

    line-height: 1; }

.box .inner {
    padding: 1em;
    background: #CCF; }

.square {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    background: red; }

.target { left: 100px; top: 150px; }
.target2 { left: 120px; top: 280px; }
```

I hope to have helped you!

Comment: Yes, you have helped. In fact, your fiddle works perfectly! Many thanks for a fast and elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

How this is done:

The position id gives the position of the entire element.

The box class defines the width and height of the box and only has borders for bottom left and right leaving the top open because the header will be there

The header class height is set to zero as to not influence the box's position and is moved up 18 px

The h4 has borders on top left and right but not on the bottom so it will not block out the box

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Positioning Test</title>
        <style>
        .header{
            position: relative;
            bottom: 18px;
            right:1px;
            background: white;
            height:0px;
        }
        .header h4{
            width: 400px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border: 1px red solid; 
            border-bottom:none;
        }
        .box{
            border: 1px red solid; 
            border-top:none;
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            background: #aaf;
        }
        #position1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="position1" class="box">
            <div class="header">
                <h4>Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="inner">
                I'm inside!
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Your code positions the heading (`header` "Title" in your example) at (50,100). That's extremely easy to do, but not what I want. I want the `inner` div precisely at (50,100) and the `header` to be dynamically positioned above that.

Comment: @type_outcast Ah I didn't see that.  I will revise my code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your body tags are are not wrapping your code.

Secondly your red box div should wrap all the other divs and be closed last. It closes early

Comment: Indeed, the opening `<body>` tag got out of position in my example. I've fixed that. Thanks! Not sure what you mean with your second comment, though; the `box1` div encloses everything but the `marker` div, which was my intent. (The `marker` is a standalone div to mark the desired target location for sake of example.)